# How to re-use FactorBot factories to build request attributes when testing with RSPEC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am refactoring an application based on Rails 5.2.4, with rspec 3.12. I focus on requests tests which do not exist yet.

While defining ***requests*** tests for the Playgrounds controller, I wish to re-use the Factories that has helped to validate the Playground model. I met several errors on the way, and I am now stumbling on the previously used login feature. Here are the first requests:

```
 RSpec.describe "/playgrounds", type: :request do
  
  # Playground. As you add validations to Playground, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.

  let(:valid_pg) {FactoryBot.create(:playground)}
  let(:invalid_pg) {FactoryBot.create(:playground, status_id: nil)} # Invalid as status is mandatory
  let(:valid_attributes) { valid_pg.attributes.except("id") } # Exclude id as it is generated
  let(:invalid_attributes) { invalid_pg.attributes.except("id") }

# Login as used in the features validation
before do
    get "/users/sign_in"
    test_user = FactoryBot.create(:user, is_admin: true)
    login_as test_user, scope: :user
end

  describe "GET /index" do
    it "1-renders a successful response" do
      valid_attributes["code"].next!

      puts valid_attributes
      puts invalid_attributes
            puts playgrounds_url
      Playground.create! valid_attributes
      get playgrounds_url
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end

  describe "GET /show" do
    it "2-renders a successful response" do
      valid_attributes["code"].next!

      playground = Playground.create! valid_attributes
      get playground_url(playground)
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
```

The following error is raised for each test:

```
 Failure/Error: login_as test_user, scope: :user

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `login_as' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Playgrounds::GETIndex:0x000001808eda7130>
```

Then I have 2 questions:

1. Re-using Factories here sounds like a good idea to avoid DRY. Is it?
2. How can I use the **login_as** method in the context of **requests**?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: On a side note I would say that if you're using factories to test your validations you're doing it wrong. Validation tests should just use `ModelName.new` and you should just pass whatever attribute you're testing in that specific test. That fact that you're using a factory leads me to belive that you're using the "carpet bombing" approach  
 (`expect(model.valid?).to be true/false`) which is useless as its so prone to false positives.

Comment: Well ... I took my approach from some tutorials: define a factory with minimum required attributes, and use it to test the model's detailed requirements such as "it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:code).case_insensitive }" etc... And then reuse the Factory in features test, and hopefully in requests tests.

Comment: That looks like you're using shoulda-matchers? Good stuff. You don't actually have to use a factory though as it will automatically set the values before the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really are missing the mark in quite a lot of ways here.

What you actually want is something more like:

```
RSpec.describe "Playgrounds", type: :request do
  # this should be done in your test setup
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods 


  # This should be handled with a trait
  let(:user) { create(:user, is_admin: true) }
  let(:playground) { FactoryBot.create(:playground) }

  before do
    # get "/users/sign_in" - don't think you actually need this
    login_as user, scope: :user
  end 

  # Describe the route and not the controller
  describe "GET /playgrounds" do
    let!(:playgrounds) { create_list(:playground, 3) }
    # Don't do that wonky numbering stuff - you don't need it 
    # and it will just confuse you when the examples run in random order
    it "renders a successful response" do
      get playgrounds_url
      # this is ok as a litmus test but doesn't tell you if the controller
      # is actually providing a meaningful response
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
    # @todo write a test that it actually responds with the playgrounds
  end

  describe "GET /playgrounds/:id" do
    it "renders a successful response" do
      get playground_url(playground)
      # this is ok as a litmus test but doesn't tell you if the controller
      # is actually providing a meaningful response
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
    # @todo write a test that it actually responds with the playground
  end

  describe "POST /playgrounds" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      # Use per context let instead 
      let(:attributes) { attributes_for(:playground) }
      it "creates a playground" do
        expect {
          post '/playgrounds', params: {
            playground: attributes
          }
        }.to change(Playground, :count).by(1)
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
    end 

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      # Use per context let instead 
      let(:attributes) do 
        # I would just define this manually
        {
          foo: ""
        }
      end
      it "doesn't create a playground" do
        expect {
          post '/playgrounds', params: {
            playground: attributes
          }
        }.to_not change(Playground, :count)
        expect(response).to have_http_status :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

`FactoryBot.create` and `create_list` should be used to populate the database as test setup. You should not use it to try to create invalid records as that will raise an error and just doesn't make sense. The specs for the index and show functionality should really just rely on the test setup to create the preconditions.

If you want to reuse the factory definition when testing the create/update actions then use `FactoryBot.attributes_for` to get a hash of attributes or `FactoryBot.build` to just get an unsaved instance of the model.

> Re-using Factories here sounds like a good idea to avoid DRY. Is it?

If you subscribe to DRY methodology then it isn't something you want to avoid. But yes, using factories can be used to avoid duplication but they do also detract from the readibility of a spec as you have to look at the factory definition to see exactly what is passed.

> How can I use the login_as method in the context of requests?

Depends entirely on what authentication system you're using. If you're using Devise you can just use the [test helpers provided by Warden](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Test/Helpers) which short-circuits the authentication system. This is much more efficient than having each test send additional HTTP requests to log a user in.

Actually going through the steps of logging in should be covered by a separate test (a feature/system spec) specifically for the authentication system.

If you have something you cobbled together yourself you would either stub the method which provides the user or go through the steps of post'ing directly to the method that signs the user in. Integration tests use a mechanism that mimics cookie handling in a browser.

PS. I don't know what `valid_attributes["code"].next!` is supposed to be doing but why is this something your tests should be concerned with? This seems like the internals are dangling out and is very smelly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations! And for the hint about Warden test helpers! It all started working when I added "include Warden::Test::Helpers" at the top of file: login operates. Now I can go forward, taking advantage of your observations. Thanks !